# Find total dropped packets : Android

Tags: android, udp, client

Is there a way to find the total number of packets dropped from a process ID?

Does TrafficStats.getUidTxPackets (int uid)  consists of the total packets (dropped + successfully transmitted)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know if a UDP packet is dropped once it has left the device.  This is fundamental to how UDP operates.